# Declaring a variable in a if/else statement that can have different types

Tags: c++

I want to choose the type of a variable given a if/else condition. For example:

```
if (something){
  int a = 5;
}
else{
  float a = 5;
}
```

The problem is that `a` will be out of scope once the if/else block is finished. And I can not declare `a` in the global scope since I don't know the type beforehand.

Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: What is the *actual* problem you want to solve with your solution? Your question is a nice example of [the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), asking us for help with a solution to an (for us) unknown problem. Perhaps there are other ways to solve the problem?

Comment: I want to declare a variable that has the same name, in this case `a`. But that the type depends on the if condition. So I want to use the command line arguments to say something like: --type=int/float/etc. And then I want the program to declare `a` as that type.

Comment: `std::variant<int, float>` might be your solution, but the rest of the code will be a mess -- C++ just isn't designed to allow variables with a varying static type. I'm seconding SomeProgrammerDude.

Comment: You could use [constexpr if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If) but that is a C++17 feature,

Comment: what do you want to do with `a` once you have created it?

Comment: I used `int/float` to simplify, but actually `a` can be two different complex objects that define a type of interface (ethernet, wifi) in a networks simulator.  Then when you create the link between 2 nodes you have to provide which type of object you want to use as a link. I wanted to be able to change all my network links by having some command line argument and I did not find a way of doing so without duplicating the entire code with a big if/else.

Answer (score 3):

We still don't really know *why* you want it, but one solution I can see is to emulate dynamic types using structures, enumerations and unions.

You could have a structure like

```
struct value
{
    enum
    {
        INT,
        FLOAT
    } type;

    union
    {
        int   i;
        float f;
    } value;
};
```

This is how some interpreters of more dynamically typed languages implement their type system.

With the upcoming C++17 standard you could use [`std::variant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) instead of unions. With older compilers there's also [Boost variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/variant.html). There's also [`std::any`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) (and of course [Boost any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/any.html)).

Another possible solution is to use a byte-array big enough to hold the largest type, and copy data from or to the array as needed into (or from) actual variables of the correct type.

Yet another possible solution is to use function overloading, and in the `if` call the (overloaded) function with a variable of the wanted type, and let the function do whatever is needed. A variant of this is to use a single templated function instead.

---

With [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44760629/declaring-a-variable-in-a-if-else-statement-that-can-have-different-types#comment76502984_44760629) I really see only one possible solution: Inheritance and polymorphism.

Have an abstract `Interface` base class, defining the common interface (functions) needed. Then have an `Ethernet` and a `WiFi` class inherit from this abstract base class. Then have a pointer to the base class, that you make point to an instance of the `Ethernet` or `WiFi` class.

Most functionality of the `Ethernet` and `WiFi` classes should be pretty much common, and can even be implemented in the base class. For the cases where special `WiFi` (or `Ethernet`) operations are needed, then [*downcast*](http://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/upcasting_downcasting.php) to the concrete class.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change/choose the genuine variable type in runtime. C++ is strongly typed. So you options are:

1. Imitate that logic some other way. For example as @Some programmer dude said - by implementing some structure, that can hold values of different types. But it has a cost - you should always ask (implicitly or explicitly) the structure for the actual type (excessive calls and checks), and the structure itself will occupy more memory. There are other techniques. But at any rate the genuine type won't be different from you expect and you'll get some overhead.
2. Limit your needs ) It is possible to implement such logic, that allows you to pick the right type, based on some constant expression, at compile time. But In this case you cannot change the type w/o recompilation. So, if your expression can be evaluated at compile time, due to performance it is strongly recommended to use template metaprogramming with SFINAE. It is quite big area, but that technique can be very useful, so I suggest to take a look into it.